# issue with wildfly cluster setup

Tags: wildfly, cluster-computing, multicast

I have downloaded Wildfly-21.0.1.Final and deployed it on different 2 different machines on the same network. I haven't modified/updated the configuration and tried to start the applications servers using the following commands, but cluster is not forming

```
./bin/standalone.sh -c standalone-full-ha.xml -b 10.1xx.2.15 --u 230.0.0.1 & (on 1st node)

./bin/standalone.sh -c standalone-full-ha.xml -b 10.1xx.2.16 --u 230.0.0.1 & (on 2nd node)
```

Basically starting with the same multicast address but nodes are not discovering each other. Both are in the same network/subnet. We were able to form a cluster with JBoss4.

The logs in respective nodes

1st Node

[org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 91) ISPN000094: Received new cluster view for channel ejb: [10.1xx.2.15|0] (1) [10.1xx.2.15]

2nd Node

[org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 91) ISPN000094: Received new cluster view for channel ejb: [10.1xx.2.16|0] (1) [10.1xx.2.16]

Any help/idea is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

WildFly's -b option sets the interface of the public interface, but not the private interface, which is the the default interface for clustering.
e.g.

```
./bin/standalone.sh -c standalone-full-ha.xml -b 10.1xx.2.15 -bprivate=10.1xx.2.15 -u 230.0.0.1
```